# Physics of relativistically spinning artifact

Tags: physics, relativity

Say we have an artifact (in a medieval-technology world).  The artifact is shaped as a solid of revolution:  perhaps a donut.  It weighs a few kg and is <1 meter across.  It is absolutely smooth and frictionless.  It is spinning about its axis at a substantial fraction of light speed, say 0.5c, and is made of some material sufficient to withstand the forces involved.

The object would have the following Newtonian properties:

- You can pick it up in your hand and move it around like anything that weighs a few kg.  It's perfectly smooth so you won't even feel it spinning.  It doesn't generate frictional heat.
- You cannot turn it no matter how hard you push.  Its axis of revolution is immovable due to the artifact's incredibly high rotational energy.
- You can set it down on the ground and it won't roll.
- As the planet rotates under the object, the object's axis of revolution remains absolutely fixed relative to an inertial frame.  This means the axis of revolution (and the object itself) will seem to slowly rotate relative to the planet over a 24 hour period, similar in concept to Foucault's pendulum.

Now my question is about the relativistic properties.  Specifically, would the object carry noticeable gravity from its dragging of space?  How fast would it have to be spinning to do so, and what direction of gravitational force would someone feel if they put their hand near it?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123423/discussion-on-question-by-causative-physics-of-relativistically-spinning-artifac).

Comment: The most interesting feature of this thing is, what is it made of. The gamma factor is round-about 1.33, meaning the kinetic energy of a particle will be something-like 33% of the m-c^2 mass equivalent. So for any possible ordinary matter it will just fly apart.

Comment: @puppetsock https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AWizardDidIt i.e. this is an artifact for a medieval-technology fantasy world, where a sufficiently powerful god or wizard can use magic to make unobtainium.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem isn't speed, it is mass**

While spinning black holes and any spinning massive objects do drag space around it using the frame dragging effect, this is only noticible on very massive objects. A few kilograms won't produce a noticable effect. The Earth is much more massive even taking into account the difference in speed and the effect of that on the Earth is difficult to measure, since it is so small. You must either observe very large objects or build very sensitive instruments.

So you probably would notice no gravity effects.

Comment: Can you give a formula showing this?  I don't fully understand the formula here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame-dragging#Mathematical_derivation or how it translates into gravitational force, but I can see that it depends on α = J/(Mc) which could be large if J (angular momentum) is large even if M is small.  And I see that for large enough α a couple terms might be different from the non-relativistic formula they also give, even with r_s very small, because those terms have r_s α as factors.  Although they are also divided by ρ so I'm not sure.

Comment: On closer inspection of that formula I guess you're right, it doesn't matter how large α is if r_s is very small.